# Is there a system-wide version of the Preferences API?

Tags: java, cross-platform, preference

In a previous question, I learned about the preferences API.  Unfortunately, it only appears to be user-specific preferences.  I also have preferences that need to be able to be set across users.  What is the platform-independent way to do that in Java?

EDIT:

Good info below, however since implementing I ran into a snag...  Tested first on my dev box (Win 7, UAC off) and it works fine.  Tried it on the first of my test VMs and it fails...  On Win 7 with UAC on, writes fail (I can do a write followed by a read and not get the value I just put in there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`systemNodeForPackage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29) and [`systemRoot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemRoot%28%29) methods of the `Preferences` class give you just what you want.

Comment: systemRoot fails if UAC is on.  :-(

Answer (score 6):

Preferences has both user and system prefs, read the docs carefully.

```
Preferences.systemRoot();
Preferences.userRoot();
```