# Java Preferences doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, preferences

Recently I build an Java application. I use Java Preferences to store some information. When I ran my application in windows XP, the application run perfectly. I can store information and get the stored information. But when I ran it in Windows 7, Java Preference failed to store the information. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you see any exception? How do you know that it did not work?

Comment: I hope it has nothing to do with registry and program files virtualization. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387

Comment: yes, there is exception, but I forgot detail of exception. I am not running Win7 now. On Windows XP when I searched in the registry, I found the stored information. But i found nothing in window 7

Comment: I believe you go security exception.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried it with UAC off?

*System* preferences can't be set from Java without UAC off or UAC elevation.

*Personal/User* preferences CAN be.

*Edit* See my old question at: [Is there a system-wide version of the Preferences API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625992/is-there-a-system-wide-version-of-the-preferences-api)

Answer (score 1):

where do you have these properties files? Isn't the problem just with lack of permissions? I regularly code on Windows Vista and except for occasional problem with permissions everything works as it should.